# unable to end call in oreo -telephony manager

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I want  a call to automatically reject when a button is touched.
for that i used to receive a PhoneStateListener callback in which i am getting mobile number and using telephony manager i as able to endcall up to marshmallow version..

when i build apk and try to execute in oreo it fails. i am getting call and the call was not rejected automatically.

here is the tried code to end the call.

```
  public void disconnectCall() {
    try {
        String serviceManagerName = "android.os.ServiceManager";
        String serviceManagerNativeName = "android.os.ServiceManagerNative";
        String telephonyName = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";
        Class<?> telephonyClass;
        Class<?> telephonyStubClass;
        Class<?> serviceManagerClass;
        Class<?> serviceManagerNativeClass;
        Method telephonyEndCall;
        Object telephonyObject;
        Object serviceManagerObject;
        telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephonyName);
        telephonyStubClass = telephonyClass.getClasses()[0];
        serviceManagerClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerName);
        serviceManagerNativeClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerNativeName);
        Method getService = // getDefaults[29];
                serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
        Method tempInterfaceMethod = serviceManagerNativeClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
        Binder tmpBinder = new Binder();
        tmpBinder.attachInterface(null, "fake");
        serviceManagerObject = tempInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, tmpBinder);
        IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerObject, "phone");
        Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
        telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
        telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("endCall");
        telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);
```

Comment: maybe it's a device specific issue? we're using the "interface ITelephony" method described below in our app, and we've tested on Oreo and it works (OnePlus 3T)

Comment: Sanjana did u get working code for oreo? I m also stuck with oreo due to restriction of MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this,**

You do not need to be a system app. First, create package [com.internal.android.telephony](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html) in your project, and put this in a file called "`ITelephony.aidl`":

First make the Interface which will handle the phone state, same as I have made.

```
interface ITelephony {      

boolean endCall();     

void answerRingingCall();      

void silenceRinger(); 

}
```

*Once you have that, you can use this code to end a call:*

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Class clazz = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
method.setAccessible(true);
ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);
telephonyService.endCall();
```

**Note:** For this to work, you need to define required permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: no error caught but end call not working...call was coming

Comment: 12-14 17:37:26.160 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 12-14 17:37:26.161 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 12-14 17:37:26.161 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err: at com.xinthe.carmode.listeners.MyPhoneStateListener.disconnectCall(MyPhoneStateListener.java:108) 12-14 17:37:26.161 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err: at com.xinthe.carmode.listeners.MyPhoneStateListener.onCallStateChanged(MyPhoneStateListener.java:51)